# How can I reset (fix) the desktop? It won't load wallpapers

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-background

I had been using Variety for a long time with my xubuntu system, but it has recently stopped working. I can't seem to be able to change the wallpaper anymore, nor can I select to "show icons" on desktop. It's like it's frozen.

The wallpaper is Ok in the login screen, though. I mean, it's shown there but not once the system loads.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Heres how to install it https://linuxhint.com/install-variety-wallpaper-linux/

Simply <$ sudo apt reinstall variety>

Comment: Variety is installed and running. The thing is that the wall paper won't show or load on the desktop. The desktop wallpaper seems to be broken, frozen, stuck. It won't change, even manually. But the login screen shows the wallpaper from variety with no problem. So it's not variety it's the session wallpaper.